PowerBI - display table containing 2 date columns - Issue with filtering segment
I am trying to display a tab of item 'DI'.
The DI table has 2 date column.
First one is the current month. Second one is the date of submission.
On my page I am filtering with a segment using current month value.
I want to display all the 'DI' Item which has a date of demand equal the current month selected value.
So far my table is well related to the current month filter. But it doesn't have any filtering action on the Date of demand value. How can I filter both colums with my unique segment ?
Both my date columns are related to a calendar table.
On that case, table should return only 4 raws
Thanks
